# How to connect from java code to remote mongodb which uses kerberos on windows system?

Tags: java, mongodb, kerberos

I am new to mongodb and kerberos. I have a remote mongodb setup which uses kerberos authentication. Now I have a windows machine and have to connect to remote mongodb instance through java code. I am using the below code which connects well, but asks for username and password during the execution which I need to avoid. I have searched a lot on google and found that I need to provide keytab file but not sure how to generate it on windows machine? Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** I don't have access to mongodb server and kerberos which are running on remote machine.

```
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "have a proper value here");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "have a proper value here");

String server = "have a valid host here";
String user = "valid user name";
String databaseName = "valid database name";


MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createGSSAPICredential(user);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(server, "valid port"), Arrays.asList(credential));
```

Comment: I'm also a bit shaky concerning kerberos, but you definitely need a kerberos installation (MIT kerberos is availably for windows) and then have a look at this: https://kb.iu.edu/d/aumh - however, kindly asking the kerberos admin to create a keytab for you is normally the best way to get one in my experience.

Comment: Hi; If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to generate a keytab on a Windows machine.  The Keytab must be generated on either a member server or a domain controller of the Active Directory domain using the ktpass.exe command.  Use the Windows Server built-in utility ktpass.exe to create the keytab.  Note that Keytabs must be created on a Windows Server OS as they cannot be created on a workstation operating system, such as Windows 7, 8 or Windows 10.  When running ktpass.exe, the Command-line shell (cmd.exe) must be run "As administrator".  If User Account Control (UAC) is enabled, that must be disabled.  The keytab must be created in such a way that it contains the service principal name, realm name, and the encrypted hash of the password of the AD user or computer account to which the service principal inside of the keytab is related.  To do this, an example command is given below.

ktpass -out centos1-dev-local.keytab -mapUser krbCentos@DEV.LOCAL +rndPass -mapOp set +DumpSalt -crypto AES256-SHA1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -princ HTTP/centos1.dev.local@DEV.LOCAL

The above command example creates a keytab named *centos1-dev-local.keytab* for use in an AD domain named DEV.LOCAL.  For additional reference, you can read more about my article on Kerberos keytabs on Microsoft Technet:  [Kerberos Keytabs – Explained](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36470.kerberos-keytabs-explained.aspx).  I frequently go back and edit it based on questions I see here in this forum.